# bpf_prog_test_run_opts returns "Unknown error 524" when trying to run eBPF program

Tags: ebpf

I'm trying to load and run a very simple eBPF program and I am faced with an obscure error code (524). The program that I'm trying to load is very simple:

```
#include "vmlinux.h"
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_exit_open")
int tracepoint__syscalls__sys_exit_open(struct trace_event_raw_sys_exit* ctx)
{
    return 0;
}

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

The eBPF program is loaded using the generated skeleton:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
        struct __sk_buff skb = {0};
        struct hello_bpf *skel;
        int prog_fd, err = 0;

        // define our BPF_PROG_RUN options with our mock data.
        struct bpf_test_run_opts opts = {
                // required, or else bpf_prog_test_run_opts will fail
                .sz = sizeof(struct bpf_test_run_opts),
                // ctx is an skb in this case
                .ctx_in = &skb,
                .ctx_size_in = sizeof(skb)
        };

        // load our fib lookup test program into the Kernel and return our
        // skeleton handle to it.
        skel = hello_bpf__open_and_load();
        if (!skel) {
                printf("[error]: failed to open and load skeleton: %d\n", err);
                return -1;
        }

        // get the prog_fd from the skeleton, and run our test.
        prog_fd = bpf_program__fd(skel->progs.tracepoint__syscalls__sys_exit_open);
        err = bpf_prog_test_run_opts(prog_fd, &opts);
        if (err != 0) {
                printf("[error]: bpf test run failed: %d\n", err); // -1
                perror("bpf_prog_test_run_opts"); // bpf_prog_test_run_opts: Unknown error 524
                return -2;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

When trying to run the compiled binary I'm faced with the error: "Unknown error 524". Can anybody point me in the right direction?

**Kernel Configuration**

```
CONFIG_BPF=y
CONFIG_HAVE_EBPF_JIT=y
CONFIG_ARCH_WANT_DEFAULT_BPF_JIT=y
# BPF subsystem
CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL=y
CONFIG_BPF_JIT=y
CONFIG_BPF_JIT_ALWAYS_ON=y
CONFIG_BPF_JIT_DEFAULT_ON=y
CONFIG_BPF_UNPRIV_DEFAULT_OFF=y
# CONFIG_BPF_PRELOAD is not set
CONFIG_BPF_LSM=y
# end of BPF subsystem
CONFIG_CGROUP_BPF=y
CONFIG_IPV6_SEG6_BPF=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_BPF=m
CONFIG_BPFILTER=y
CONFIG_BPFILTER_UMH=m
CONFIG_NET_CLS_BPF=m
CONFIG_NET_ACT_BPF=m
CONFIG_BPF_STREAM_PARSER=y
CONFIG_LWTUNNEL_BPF=y
CONFIG_BPF_EVENTS=y
CONFIG_BPF_KPROBE_OVERRIDE=y
CONFIG_TEST_BPF=m
```

**Makefile**

```
all: hello.bpf.o hello.skel.h test

hello.bpf.o: hello.bpf.c
    clang -target bpf -Wall -O2 -c $<

hello.skel.h: hello.bpf.o
    bpftool gen skeleton $< > $@

test: test.c
    gcc -Wall -o $@ $< -lbpf
    

.PHONY:
clean:
    rm -rf hello.bpf.o
    rm -rf hello.skel.h
    rm -rf test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

524 is the error code for `ENOTSUPP`, meaning the operation is not supported.

And checking [the sources](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7-rc1/source/kernel/trace/bpf_trace.c#L1725), **`BPF_PROG_RUN` is indeed not supported for programs of type tracepoint**. It seems to be [supported for raw tracepoints](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7-rc1/source/kernel/trace/bpf_trace.c#L2036), so you could try that (though that will depend on the kernel version).

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you very much (:

Comment: You are most welcome! I hope you find a way to make it work.

Comment: I did; thanks for that! I even put out a simple example: https://github.com/tomwassing/xdp-test-example